# Why does this code for a recursive preorder traversal on a binary tree work? Shouldn't it get stuck at the first recursive call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def preorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
        out = []
        def preorder(node):
            if not node: return

            out.append(node.val)
            preorder(node.left)
            preorder(node.right)

            return

        preorder(root)
        return out
```

This code is the code I saw in the solutions, it almost makes sense to me other than the recursive function calls. I understand it is return the correct solution, but I'm unsure why it works.

I have ran the code myself and it 100% works and passes all the LeetCode test cases. The part I'm Struggling to understand is the 2nd recursive function call:

```py
            out.append(node.val)
            preorder(node.left)
            preorder(node.right) # This one here
```

What I'm struggling to understand is why/how the code ever hits this point. To me, the code should never hit this point, as there is a recursive function call prior that has no condition to be met. Why isn't the code just continuously attempting to run the line before? (`preorder(node.left)`).

The only explanation I can think of, is that because when we are on the final node that would be applicable to the first recursive call, we would then be passing in None/Null. Does python know that this would result in nothing happening and skip to the next line? How is it actually possible for `preorder(node.right)` to be executed when `preorder(node.left)` exists above it, and requires no conditionals to be met to execute?

Comment: because u r passing a new node in each recursive call (node.left) and for that call next step ie right part that node value stayed in stacked

Comment: A recursive call isn't a goto to the top of the function. It's a new function call, and after it finishes, the current function call resumes.

Comment: @khelwood I understand now, and it makes sense it works haha. Thanks.

Comment: In the code `print("hi"); print("bye")`, you'd expect `print("bye")` to run after `print("hi")` returns, wouldn't you? Recursion is not fundamentally different than normal function calls. The caller waits until the sub-call is done, then resumes control. If the sub-call spawns other calls, it waits for those. A program is a big stack of function calls blocking waiting for their sub-calls to complete so they can regain control, possibly use results returned by the sub-call and keep working through their code. Eventually, they all resolve and pop off the stack and the program ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion stops at this line:

```
    if not node: return
```

So, when there are no more left nodes, this happens:

```
        out.append(node.val)
        preorder(node.left)  # Return None
        preorder(node.right) # Starting going to the right
```

You might imagine that as the function goes all the left nodes are appended while the right nodes wait until there are no more left nodes.

A good exercise is to run this code in debug mode

ps: This process is known as Depth-First Search (DFS), where it goes as deep as it can into the tree before backtracking and going to the right node.